# How can I implement the following example without using "any"

Tags: typescript, generics, methods, call, any

I have some classes let's call them `ExampleClassOne` and `ExampleCLassTwo`:

```
abstract class AbstractExampleClass {
    protected member: SomeClass;

    constructor(member: SomeClass) {
        this.member = member;
    }
}


class ExampleClassOne extends AbstractExampleClass {
    
    public methodOne() {
        // Do something
    }

    public methodTwo() {
        // Do something different
    }
}

class ExampleClassTwo extends AbstractExampleClass {
    
    public methodThree() {
        // Do something
    }

    public methodFour() {
        // Do something different
    }
}
```

And I have a config which looks like this:

```
const config = {
    classes: 
    [
        {
            className: ExampleClassOne 
            methods: 
            [
                {
                    method: 'methodOne',
                },
                {
                    method: 'methodeTwo',
                },
            ]

        },
        {
            className: ExampleClassTwo 
            methods: 
            [
                {
                    method: 'methodThree',
                },
                {
                    method: 'methodeThree',
                },
            ]

        },
        
    ]

}
```

Now I iterate over the the config array with an inner iteration over the methods array like this:

```
for(let i = 0; i < config.length; i++) {
    const configClass = config.classes[i];
    for(let j = 0; j < configClass.methods.length) {
        initializeObjectAndCallMethod(configClass.name, configClass.methods[j].method);
    }
};
```

`initializeObjectAndCallMethod` looks like that:

```
initializeObjectAndCallMethod(className: {new (member: SomeClass): any}, methodName: string): void {
    const memberObject = new SomeClass();
    const object = new className(memberObject );
    const method = methodName as keyof typeof object;
    
    if(object.hasOwnProperty(method)) {
        object[method]();
    }
}
```

If I use any in the function declaration like this - `initializeObjectAndCallMethod(class: {new (member: SomeClass): any}, methodName: string)` - everything works fine.

An approach to not using any was exchanging any with `AbstractExampleClass` like this: `initializeObjectAndCallMethod(className: {new (member: SomeClass): AbstractExampleClass}, methodName: string): void`. But this throws the error: This expression is not callable. Type 'never' has no call signatures. Because, as @geoffrey pointed out, there is no public member on `AbstractExampleClass` and the linter doesn't know anything about the Classes I'm passing from the config.

And that's where my question comes in: is there any possibility to not using "any" there or another way to achieve what I'm doing there?

Comment: `AbstractExampleClass` does not have any member, so `keyof AbstractExampleClass` is `never`.

Comment: by the way, you should avoid using the `class` keyword as a variable / parameter / property name

Comment: @geoffrey its an example. i could have named anything else but for you i will change it.

Comment: @geoffrey `AbstractExampleClass` has a member called member. But that's not the point.

Comment: @geoffrey The point is, that my abstract class is there for defining the constructor and the member called member and for being parent of the child classes, so i could tell the linter which kind of class i want to pass to the function. My question point to the fact, that this example works fine if i tell the linter the type of the passed parameter is any but how do i do it the right way.

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke: `member` is protected, so there is no *public* member and `keyof AbstractExampleClass` is `never`.

Comment: @geoffrey, you are right. But that's still not the point. Maybe i have to change my question. I'll think about it and change it when i know what's the right question to my problem.